# Can I take this computer to US?

Tags: power-supply, power

I am moving to US. Electricity network in my home country is 220v. I want to take [this pc](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c03001584) with me but not sure if it fits the electricity in US. Would appreciate your help.

```
Power supply
Active Power Factor Correction (PFC) power supply assembly - Rated at 300 W, (Merlot-E)
656721-001
Power supply 300 W, 85% efficient
575437-001
250-W (max) power supply (Zinfandel), Bestec ATX-250, 12 V), 100 - 120 V ac and 200 - 240 V ac input 50/60 Hz (switch selectable), Non Power Form Correction
```

Answer (score 2):

The below diagram from Wikipedia gives us some idea of the variation between countries. North American power outlets provide 120 volts at 60 Hz. Outlets in Europe provide 230 volts at 50 Hz. Voltages vary in other countries, too.
[image]

Read the small print on your devices to find out whether they support the voltages you need. For example, look at the print on your smartphone or laptop charging adapter. If you see something like the following, the adapter is rated to work both in North America and Europe:

```
100-240V 50/60Hz
```

Chargers for laptops, smartphones, and tablets are often compatible with both voltage standards. However, you shouldn’t take this for granted — look at the fine print on every adapter before plugging it in. For example, Nintendo 3DS charging adapters are not compatible with both voltage standards.

[image]

If your device is rated to work with the voltages in the country you’re visiting, all you need to do is use a plug adapter to connect it to the different physical plug.

If you have devices that aren’t rated to work with the voltages in the country you’re visiting, you’ll need a “**voltage converter**” that plugs into the foreign outlet and converts the electricity to a different voltage. You can purchase multiple-outlet surge protectors with built-in voltage converters or use single-outlet converters. Not all surge protectors are voltage converters — make sure you’re buying the right one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

> Power supply 300 W, 85% efficient 575437-001 250-W (max) power supply
>   (Zinfandel), Bestec ATX-250, 12 V), **100 - 120 V ac** and 200 - 240 V
>   ac input 50/60 Hz (**switch selectable**), Non Power Form Correction

See bolt text above. The PSU is capable of being switched from 220v to 110v (required for the US) Find the switch, it might be a jumper and you are golden. If you cant find a switch anywhere user friendly accessible then it automatically switches depending on the load detected.